# Upload Very Large File to Swift Container

Tags: java, upload, openstack-swift, jclouds

I'm using jclouds java SDK to upload to Swift Container i saw the code in which i upload as a multipart,i already upload as a multipart as input stream using the code

```
    try (ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)) {
                    ///input here is InputStream not ByteSource
                    Payload payload = Payloads.newInputStreamPayload(inputStream);
                    Blob blob = blobStore.blobBuilder(path).payload(payload).build();
                    ///sednig the request
                    blobStore.putBlob(ContainerName, blob, multipart());
                    System.out.println(String.format("End upload all Parts, parts number=%s, part size=%s", strPartsCount, strPartSize));  
}
```

but i have a case where i have a very large file, the input to it is a bytes matrix, the solution is very easy which is put the same code in a `for loop` and each loop the input is an index of the matrix (which is a byte array)

but the question is, would the OpenStack consider each loop (multipart upload) is linked to the previous part? how to do that?
you can say a multipart inside a multipart

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jclouds offers two options:

1) Call the individual multipart methods, e.g., `initiateMultipartUpload`, `uploadMultipartPart`, and `completeMultipartUpload`.

2) Create an `InputStream` or `ByteSource` payloads which concatenates individual parts, e.g. `SequenceInputStream` or `ByteSource.concat`.

Note that using `ByteSource.wrap(bytes)` instead of `ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)` makes the payload repeatable and jclouds will retry on network errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot, one more question, **does any of the two methods that you have mentioned has an advantage over the other one**? because most of multipart upload cases i use the second method, or the method that they are mentioned in the jclouds examples

Comment: You should prefer the second option since it can handle minimum part sizes and other sundries.

Comment: and i believe if a network error or any other error it will be handled as well, right?

Comment: jclouds will handle network errors if you provide a repeatable Payload like ByteSource.